# Report Parameter Values in SSRS

Tags: sql-server-2005, reportingservices-2005

I need to generate semi-monthly (1-15 and 16-last day of month) and monthly reports based on the same report template. I put two parameters on the report template. The second parameter will be the date of execution, which it 15 and last day of month. I can define it on the report parameter when I design the report. I do not want to create 3 report templates to take care of it. Do you know how I can define the 1st and 16th of each month on the first Report Parameter Values in report subscription on the report manager. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For the begin date, set the default value to "Non-queried" and enter

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), 1)
```

That will get you the first of the month, which will be wrong 1/3 of the time.

In a similar fashion, for the end date

```
=DateSerial(Year(Now), Month(Now), Day(Now))
```

Which works all the time, assuming it's as you describe - Now is either the 15th or the end of the month.